# Windows sidebar gadget - receiving list from webhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm looking for a way to display a list of info from webhost to windows sidebar gadget. 
I can see a solution using iframe, but i know it's really not a smart idea to actually use it.
I've read that there is a way to do this with some kind of javascript ajax (XmlHttpRequest) thingy. And also a refreshing function could be nice.

Comment: and what eaxctly is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [app.js](http://www.appjs.org) or [tidesdk.org](http://www.tidesdk.org/) to build interactive desktop apps using your html + css + javascript (and php) knowledge. But i don't know it can build desktop side bar gadget. Also here is a very [good tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb456468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for building windows sidebar gadget. you can refer to it.